# Pandas drop a column in a copied table but original table will follow to drop that column

Tags: python, pandas

I try to understand this problem, but I didn't found the solution, maybe the searching question is wrong. Here to elaborate my question, I have made a copy of a table (original table named **toy_table**), the copied table is named **copy_toy_table**.

```
toy_table = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[100, 2, 3], [288, 8, 9], [105, 5, 6], [207, 10, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
toy_table
```

[image]

I simply make a copy of the table, named **copy_toy_table**

```
copy_toy_table = toy_table
copy_toy_table
```

[image]

Then, I would like to remove the row in **copy_toy_table** by filter out certain value based on column

```
delete_index = copy_toy_table[copy_toy_table['a'] < 200 ].index
copy_toy_table.drop(delete_index , inplace=True)
```

As required, the row which has value lower than 200 in column 'a' were dropped.

[image]

However, when I check on the original table, **toy_table**, I found that same row which has lower than 200 in 'a' column have been dropped. I was assume that the **toy_table** will not be affected since I only make drop in **copy_toy_table**

[image]

I keen to get your advice. I truly appreciate and will learn from this. Thank you.

Comment: you should make a copy `copy_toy_table = toy_table.copy()`

Comment: This `copy_toy_table = toy_table` does not creates a copy

Comment: Hi Anky and Dani, thank you for the advice, now I get it, I truly appreciate your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just make a real copy and not a reference:

```
copy_toy_table = toy_table.copy()
```

**explaination**

when you called `copy_toy_table = toy_table` you didnt make a copy, you referenced the same object with another name, and unless you are going to referance it again, all actions you make on it will reflect to the other object...

in addition you could do...

```
toy_table = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[100, 2, 3], [288, 8, 9], [105, 5, 6], [207, 10, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
delete_index = toy_table [toy_table['a'] < 200 ].index
copy_toy_table = toy_table.drop(delete_index) # without inplace arg

copy_toy_table 
Out[x]: 
     a   b  c
1  288   8  9
3  207  10  9

toy_table
Out[x + 1]: 
     a   b  c
0  100   2  3
1  288   8  9
2  105   5  6
3  207  10  9
```

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
toy_table = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[100, 2, 3], [288, 8, 9], [105, 5, 6], [207, 10, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
toy_table

copy_toy_table = toy_table.copy()
copy_toy_table

delete_index = copy_toy_table[copy_toy_table['a'] < 200 ].index
copy_toy_table.drop(delete_index , inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
In[1]: copy_toy_table
Out[2]: 
     a   b  c
1  288   8  9
3  207  10  9

toy_table
Out[3]: 
     a   b  c
0  100   2  3
1  288   8  9
2  105   5  6
3  207  10  9
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, I truly appreciate your help!